# jQuery after function doesn't seem to be working correctly for tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Due to a table plugin I am using, I have to resort to using jQuery to add a div around a table after the fact.  I am trying to use before/after functions but it doesn't appear to be working.
Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/LWXQK/1/

Jquery code:

```
$('#dashboard').before("<div class='reclass'>");
$('#dashboard').after("</div>");
```

Expected result:

```
<div class='reclass'><table id='dashboard'></table></div>
```

Actual result:

```
<div class='reclass'></div><table id='dashboard'></table>
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be or an alternative?

Comment: `DOM` stands for Document **Object** Model, not for  Document String Model.

Comment: @connexo, you do realize this question is 5 years old, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how DOM functions, you should add an element to the DOM, jQuery calls `createElement()` method of the `document` object behind the scene, since the first parameter passed to `.before()` is valid `.before()` inserts an element before the table, however the second parameter is not and `.after()` doesn't do anything, otherwise it would insert another element after the table,  you can use `.wrap()` method:

```
$('#dashboard').wrap("<div class='reclass'></div>");
```